# X-Accel-Redirect for mp4 gives unsupported video type on Internet Explorer Windows 7 only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, nginx, html5-video, x-accel-redirect

I'm trying to serve up an mp4 in an html5 `video` tag using NGINX `X-Accel-Redirect` header.  Here's a sample link (second video works, is served directly):

https://www.sonoclipshare.com/testfiles/test.htm

Works perfectly for mp4s for Chrome/Safari/FF, but getting an error on IE 11 on Windows 7 only. Further, I can use X-Accel-Redirect to deliver any other file in the manner (via xfiles.php below) - it works fine on Win7/IE11.

> Unsupported video type or invalid file path.

The video works perfectly on IE when served directly. I suspect it's something specific to how I've got my headers. Here's the simple html:

```
<video width="800" controls>
  <source src="xfiles.php?&file=001.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And `xfiles.php`:

```
include('../cururl.php');
$murl = curPageURL();
parse_str($murl, $result);
$filename=$result['file'];
$folder=$result['folder'];
$file="/var/www/uploads/" . $folder . "/" . $filename;
$aliasedFile = '/protected/' . $folder .'/' . $filename;
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' .(string)(filesize($file)) );
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $aliasedFile);
exit;
```

Here's the output of running `curl -I` on the file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 13:50:47 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 1489903
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dae73721e3830a2bde51f3809bb87c47a1493387447; expires=Sat, 28-Apr-18 13:50:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.sonoclipshare.com; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 12:18:10 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2i6k2qjsrgs94ca8tu7uadb74; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="001.mp4"
ETag: "59033302-16bbef"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 356a7e1a0af542e8-ATL
```

And here is the `curl -I` result for a directly served (working) file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 15:34:31 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 1489903
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d1a0bcd70223005a0b5275494f71db40f1493393671; expires=Sat, 28-Apr-18 15:34:31 GMT; path=/; domain=.sonoclipshare.com; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 13:45:59 GMT
ETag: "59034797-16bbef"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 356b16116cf25e82-TPA

URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
/testfiles/xfiles.php?file=002a.mp4&folder=R4mtqwYN3d   HTTPS   GET (Aborted)   text/html   278 B   62 ms       94  31  31  0   0   147
```

DETAILS (REQUEST):

```
Key Value
Request GET /testfiles/xfiles.php?file=002a.mp4&folder=R4mtqwYN3d HTTP/1.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept  */*
Referer https://www.sonoclipshare.com/testfiles/test.htm
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG 1
Pragma  getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    www.sonoclipshare.com
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cookie  __cfduid=dfc9dd3e27defddfbafa2c0a6dbdab2151493386292; _ga=GA1.2.832748637.1493386815
```

DETAILS(RESPONSE):

```
Key Value
Server  nginx/1.11.3
Response    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Keep-Alive  timeout=20
Date    Tue, 02 May 2017 13:54:25 GMT
Content-Type    text/html
Content-Length  178
Content-Disposition inline; filename=""
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   public, must-revalidate
```

Comment: in asp.net you use a response.close() instead of response.flush().... don't know the equivalent in php.

Comment: IE has security restrictions on navigation into zones of lower integrity and a 'same origin' policy.... first set up IE to record dev console messages for blocked content and markup errors... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"... save changes... The IE dev tool will now list (otherwise suppressed) messages for Blocked content, XSS and markup errors. To use the Networking tab of dev tools, pin it to your browser and then click the start button, to record request and response codes on the client.

Comment: thanks.  after enabling error logging I'm getting the result in my updates answer

Comment: removing the SAMEORIGIN header didn't fix the problem, still same 'Aborted' GET request

Comment: Double click on the aborted response in the IE networking tab, and post a copy of the details in its header..... a reproduction link would be good for us to help you.... I'm guessing that the filesize in the header does not match the actual mp4 file. Other browsers do not have security zones like MSIE browsers... its finicky about what it will eat.

Comment: ... we would also like to know which IE security zones the domain of your site and the domain of the video source map to.... use the File>Properties menu in IE ......

Comment: here is a web search that you may like to research..... reasons why IE aborts a file request... http://www.bing.com/search?q=resons+why+IE+aborts+a+file+request

Comment: Updated my answer w/ a same link and output as requested.  Using IE11, don't see Properties under File. Under the Internet Options > Security I see that my browser is set to Medium-High w/ Protected Mode checked, this was the default when installing IE.  No other mapping to this site specifically.

Comment: Hi, your web link works for me... If you are developing on your own computer and using your computer's localhost sever, try the test page you provided, if it works for you then post back...the fix is to set up your development and testing environment. Another possible fix may be just one of your settings in IE. go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, Multimedia section, check "Enable alternative codecs in HTML5 media elements". !important you have to restart your computer for the changes to take affect...after restarting test again.

Comment: Interesting.  It _does_ work fine on Windows 10/IE11, but still fails on Windows 7/IE11.  Anything special about Win7 I should expect?

Comment: media codecs? did you check the settings and reboot? where did the mp4 cardiographs come from?

Comment: I encoded these using ffmpeg. _alternative codecs in HTML5 media elements_ is already checked.  Further, the second clip works fine, only the  X-Accel-Redirected clip fails.

Comment: Anything special about Win7 I should expect? from my research no(my win7 machine is not used much and is out of date)....It is likely to be a settings/security issue....so on your win7 machine, first go Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default", save changes. Next find out which security zones your site/test site maps to from the Files>Properties menu.... you should see either Internet, Intranet site.

Comment: also.... setting for media licenses....Tools>Manage Media licenses..... download the licenses if prompted. Restart your win7 computer. running out of comment space here. so this may be my  last post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143334/discussion-between-ultrasoundjelly-and-rob-parsons).

Comment: Hey @UltrasoundJelly, I recently ran into a similar issue. I was serving up mp3 through a webserver and all browsers worked except IE.. and it was because the `Content-Type` of my response was coming as `application/octet-stream` instead of the correct `audio/mpeg`. Why is NGINX setting up your type to `text/html`?

Comment: The curl response shows the correct content type is being sent.  For some reason IE11 on Windows 7 only is getting this text/html response type, I suspect because it's getting a 403 forbidden.  The filename isn't even being received in the response header.